# textBox1_Leave in wpf

Tags: wpf, events

What is the equivalent Following code in wpf

code in winapp :

```
        private void textBox1_Leave(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("www.stackoverflow.com");
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
private void textBox1_LostFocus(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    MessageBox.Show("www.stackoverflow.com");
}
```

(actually you could even reuse the same signature as before, all you need to do is hook the method to the `LostFocus` event instead of the `Leave` event)